# How to wait for a Dart Future to complete, synchronously

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Say, I have an async function that I want to call in a synchronous function. For example:

```
Future<int> foo() async {
  // do something
  return 109;
}

int bar() {
  var r = wait_for_future(foo());
  return r;
}
```

What I'm looking for is a possible implementation for `wait_for_future`. Can this even be done in Dart?

Comment: [await](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures)?

Comment: `await` can't be used in a non-async function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *provisional* [dart:cli](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-cli/dart-cli-library.html) – `waitFor` which allows one to synchronously wait for an async method.

This is only available on the Dart VM, though.

Comment: It sounds like this is the best that can be found for now. Thanks.

Comment: `waitFor` [is deprecated](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.0/dart-cli/waitFor.html)

Answer (score 3):

No, [Dart is single-threaded](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop#darts-single-thread-of-execution), and it is not possible to block the main thread waiting for an asynchronous task:

> Once a Dart function starts executing, it continues executing until it exits. In other words, Dart functions can’t be interrupted by other Dart code.

That means that there is no way to *pause* and wait for other Dart code to execute.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct conclusion, as this can be done, for example, in Python single-threaded code, using `run_until_complete`. It might be so that this is not possible in Dart, but being single-threaded is not in conflict with being able to yield to event-loop.

Comment: Right, which is why I said _Dart_ can't do that.

Comment: I'm simply saying that can't be inferred from Dart being single-threaded, nor from the part of the docs you cite. And I'm not asking about _preemption_, but about _yielding_.

Comment: What about Isolates? If I use multiple Isolates, I should be able to block one (by waiting actively) without blocking the entire application.